# install4j5 to install4j7 upgrade issue on Bamboo

Tags: install4j

I have upgraded from install4j5 to install4j7 on my Bamboo server and now I am getting a Java version error.

15-May-2019 20:52:19    [install4j] install4j version 7.0.10 (build 7329), built on 2019-03-14
15-May-2019 20:52:19    [install4j] Using Java 1.8.0_101 from /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
15-May-2019 20:52:21    [install4j] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: The Java minimum version for the project must be 1.7 or higher.

I'm using 1.8 as seen in the log. I have not been able to find any settings that are pointing install4j7 to another version.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the project in the install4j IDE, go to the "General Settings->Java Version" step. There is a text field labeled "Minimum version" that has to be 1.7 or higher when using install4j 7.x.